# List of basic scriptures to know about Hindu philosophy

Tags: scripture, book-recommendation, manuscripts

So far I know, Hinduism does not have one master book, rather it is a synthesis of many related religions and/or cultures and/or philosophical points of view, that roots back to Indus valley civilisation. Initially there wasn't a scripture. But later on they were written in various kind of plant materials (Like coconut leaves, palm leaves, birch bark etc), and in rare cases rock carvings or metal inscriptions.

Unfortunately I don't know almost anything about the Hindu scriptures and what does they say. Therefore I am looking for a comprehensive list for reading.

A few books about I have heard about:

1. The Vedas
2. The Upanishadas
3. The Ramayana (Epic)
4. The Mahabharata (Epic)
5. Geeta or The Srimadbhagabat Geeta
6. Natyasastra by Bharata Muni  (Probably a book on Music theory)

However, there are many other books which I do not know about. Such as different aspects and sects of Hinduism (Like code of conduct, society, mythology, spiritual practices and pathways) Can you please provide a list about the books?

Answer (score 0):

We have too limited time to read Vedas. You should study Shrimadbhagwatgita and Upnishadas in beginning. Then you can study shrimadbhagwat puran .

Answer (score 0):

This question is very up for debate, but I would suggest first looking into the Six Darshanas ie (Minamsa, Nyaya, Vaisheshika, Yoga, Samkhya, and Vedanta), then pick one as some books we all know and love aren't authentic in all schools. Each Darshana has a Sutra and various later works. Other than that Dharmashastras and Dharmasutras are pretty much accepted by most schools in some way or another. I will give an example of learning Vishsitadvaiata a school in Vedanta Darshana. I am reading modern works, by authentic persons with scriptural justification as proof. Then, read Puranas related to that school to get a basic ground of Vaishnava philosophy. Afterwards, I will wait till I can get an initiation to read more advanced works like Sri Bhashya.